Alignment Issue inside RadzenStack
I'm working on a Blazor project using Radzen components, and I'm struggling to align a form and button horizontally within the same row using flexbox. The form contains dropdowns, and I want the button to sit next to the dropdowns, but the alignment seems off.
Here's my code:
<RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Class="align-items-center" Style="display: flex; gap: 20px; align-items:center;">
    <RadzenFormField Text="" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 10px;">
        <ChildContent>
            <RadzenDropDown />
        </ChildContent>
    </RadzenFormField>

        <RadzenFormField Text="" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 10px;">
            <ChildContent>
                <RadzenDropDown  />
            </ChildContent>
        </RadzenFormField>
    <RadzenButton Text="Add Members" Click="buttonClick" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center;" />
</RadzenStack>

How can I ensure that the RadzenFormField and RadzenButton are properly aligned within the same row using flexbox in this layout?

You applied <RadzenFormField> and <ChildContent> for (wrapping) both <RadzenDropDown> but not <RadzenButton>. The rendered HTML:
<div class="rz-form-field">
  <div class="rz-form-field-content">
    <!-- Radzen Dropdown Content but not our focus -->
  </div>
</div>

From the .rz-form-field-content CSS:
.rz-form-field-content {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-block: var(--rz-form-field-margin-block);
    margin-inline: var(--rz-form-field-margin-inline);
    box-shadow: var(--rz-form-field-shadow);
    transition: var(--rz-input-transition);
}

With margin-block this will add additional margin-top (8px) for the (dropdown) container. Thus this will not align with your <RadzenButton> as it doesn't have this style rule.

Two approaches can be achieved:
Approach 1: Add margin-block: var(--rz-form-field-margin-block) rule to <RazdenButton>.
<RadzenButton Text="Add Members" Click="buttonClick" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center; margin-block: var(--rz-form-field-margin-block)" />

Approach 2: Wrap <RazdenButton> in the <RazdenFormField> and <ChildContent> with customized style.
Customized style is needed to remove the border when rendering and focusing on it.
<style>
    .rz-form-field.no-border .rz-form-field-content {
        border: 0; 
        box-shadow: none;
    }
</style>

<RadzenFormField Class="no-border" Text="" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 10px;">
    <ChildContent>
        <RadzenButton Text="Add Members" Style="height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center;" />
    </ChildContent>
</RadzenFormField>

